# Do isomorphisms of projective varieties preserve lines?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field, let $L$ be a line defined over $k$ in a closed $k$-subvariety $X$ of $\mathbb P^n_k$ for some $n$, and let $f:X\rightarrow X'$ be an isomorphism over $k$ to a closed $k$-subvariety $X'$ of $\mathbb P^m_k$ for some $m$ (not necessarily equal to $n$).

Is $f(L)$ a line inside $X'$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. As a trivial example, think of the isomorphism between a conic $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ and $X'=\mathbb{P}^1$. More generally, $Y=\mathbb{P}^1$ and its (degree $\geq 2$) Veronese image $Y'$ are isomorphic but the latter is not a line.

The point is whether $f$ preserves the corresponding very ample invertible sheaves. If this is the case, lines are sent to lines.

Comment: Thank you! Nice example

Answer (score 1):

The projective line is isomorphic to a smooth conic.

Comment: Thank you! Nice example